# Sigma-algebra independent from itself

Tags: measure-theory

How can I construct a measure $\mu$ such that a $\sigma$-algebra $A$ on a non-empty set $X$ is independent from itself, that is $\mu(B \cap C)=\mu(B)\mu(C)$ for every $B,C\in A$.
Thank you

Comment: Do you want anything more from this measure? There's at least one obvious and completely useless one that springs to mind, for example.

Answer (score 3):

This can only be a 0-1-measure. Indeed, if $\mu(C)=a\neq 0$, then $\mu(C) = \mu(C\cap C) = \mu(C)^2$, which only has solutions $\mu(C)=1$ or $\mu(C)=0$. So, $\mu(B)=1$ or $\mu(B)=0$ for all $B$.

Answer (score 1):

From $\mu(B)=\mu(B\cap B)=\mu(B)^2$, you get that $\mu(B)$ is $0$ or $1$.

If $B\cap C=\emptyset$, then $0=\mu(B\cap C)=\mu(B)\mu(C)$.

If $\mu(B)=1$ for a certain $B$, then $\mu(C)=1$ for all $C\supset B$.

So an example would be any Dirac measure $\delta_{x_0}$ for $x_0\in X$ and $\mathcal A=\mathcal P(X)$.

Or more generally, fix a set $B_0\subset X$, take $\mathcal A$ any $\sigma$-algebra with $B_0\in\mathcal A$ and such that no nonempty proper subset of $B_0$ is in $\mathcal A$, and define $\mu(B)=1$ if $B_0\subset B$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Your "more generally" does not work: if $B_0$ has a nonempty proper subset $S \in\mathcal  A$,
then $\mu(S) = 0$ and $\mu(B_0 \backslash S) = 0$ which would imply $\mu(B_0) = 0$.  So $B_0$ must be an "atom" of the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: indeed, thanks. Originally I was about to write "the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $B_0$", then realized that it was too trivial for my taste. Edited.